Why does this htaccess rule blocking certain user agents crash my server?
I'm trying to block spambots using an htaccess rule based on their user agents.
Here's the rule I added:
# Block via User Agent
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(PetalBot|BlexBot|SemrushBot|MJ12Bot|DotBot| AhrefsBot|DataForSeoBot|Go-http-client).*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
#</IfModule>

Pretty sure that matches the syntax I've seen here and elsewhere for solving precisely this problem—but when I turn that code on, I get a generic Wordpress "Internal Server Error."
I expected the site to display as usual for everyone NOT using one of those agents. Instead... site down. :-(
Fairly sure that none of those user agents are mine—and I've tried taking them out out one by one, with no change.
Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Go check what the server's error log has to say.

Do you really have a space in the middle of your regex pattern - |DotBot| AhrefsBot|?

And is the closing </IfModule> really commented out as you posted it here in the question? That would most likely mean a sematic error in the file.

That erroneous "space in the middle of your regex pattern" (in the middle of the argument) would certainly result in an "Internal Server Error" since it's syntactically invalid. ("AhrefsBot|DataForSeoBot|Go-http-client).*$ is not a valid flags argument"). Spaces are argument delimiters in Apache config files. @CBroe

@MrWhite I know that, but I don't know if OP does, so that why I was asking. But I couldn't be sure if that space was actually there (what sense should it make?), or was introduced while posting the code here.

:sigh: Yup. It was the space before "AhrefsBot"—which I wasn't reading as a space, because the line on my text editor broke there. Thank you so much. I knew I'd probably feel stupid when I found out what was wrong—but at least the problem is fixed!
